# Call to a member function user() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to get the author of a post from users table both tables are created and both has relations. i have this code in my controller

```
public function viewPost($id)
    {   
        $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $by = $post->user()->get();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $this->layout->content = View::make('interface.viewPost')
        ->with('posts', $post )
        ->with('users',$user)
        ->with('date',$mytime)
        ->with('by',$by);

    }
```

and this are the models of users/posts

Posts model:
    class Post extends Eloquent{

```
        protected $fillable = array('email', 'password','title','content');

        protected $table = 'posts';

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
        }
}
```

and My Users model

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';


    protected $fillable = array('email','password','title','content');

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


    public function getRememberToken() 
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }


    public function setRememberToken($value) 
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }


    public function getRememberTokenName() 
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post','user_id');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that you want to load the user of the post you are getting. try the following

```
public function viewPost($id)
{   
    $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $post = Post::with('user')->find($id);
    $by = $post->user;
    ...

}
```

you don't even need to send `$by` to the view as you can from inside the view now do `$post->user->username`

Comment: thanks working fine now i used the second method you suggested :))

Comment: wait got this new error Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\seanroger\thesis\app\views\interface\viewPost.blade.php)

Comment: do you have posts with non-existing user? or are you trying to get a property on one of the users which isn't set? what's your view complaining on?

Comment: try
  {
   include $__path;
  }
  catch (\Exception $e)
  {
   $this->handleViewException($e, $obLevel);
  }
  you mean this?

Comment: this error return when i click my like button.                                                 public function like($id)
 {
  $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
  $post->likes++;
  $post->save();

  return Redirect::route('viewPost');
 }

Comment: The object on your user object you are trying to call... your error should be somewhere where you did `$post->user->...` also check what try `dd($post-user);` and check if you're data is set correctly

Comment: data is set correctly, it returns the user who posted. this errors returns when i like the like button.

Comment: public function like($id) { $post = Post::findOrFail($id); $post->likes++; $post->save(); return Redirect::route('viewPost'); }

Comment: Be bit more descriptive about what the error you are getting. We aren't here to write your code. If this is no longer related to this issue, accept the answer and ask a new question